# Different behavior of app in open and done after installation succefull

Tags: android, background-process, foreground

My android app used to got killed in background even with foreground service. 
Here is the manifest entry for the service :

```
 <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:label="TritonHK"
            android:process=":my_process" >
        </service>
```

and here is the code for service

```
 MLog.w(getClass().getName(), "TritonHK started");

         Notification note=new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
                                             "TritonHK is running",
                                             System.currentTimeMillis());
         Intent i=new Intent(this, BGMessages.class);

         i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

         PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                                                     i, 0);

         note.setLatestEventInfo(this, "TritonHK",
                                 "TritonHK",
                                 pi);
         note.flags|=Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;

         startForeground(1337, note);
```

and here is how I am starting my service:

```
Intent i=new Intent(this, MyService.class);

        startService(i);
```

I am starting the service in onCreate of my first activity.

I have over come this bug by removing  `android:process=":my_process"` from my service in manifest, now it looks like this:

```
 <service
                android:name=".MyService"
                android:icon="@drawable/icon"
                android:label="TritonHK"
                 >
            </service>
```

But now I am facing an interesting problem.

When I install the app on my device and after installation successful I click on `done` and launch my app from the icon, It runs fine.

But after installation successful If I launch the app by clicking `open` button It got killed in background for very first time. Then If I force close the app and launch it from icon again then it runs fine.

I am puzzled what is going wrong. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the problem with the following code and posting the same so that others can also use this.

I have added below code to the on create of my launcher activity.

```
if (!isTaskRoot()) {
            final Intent intent = getIntent();
            final String intentAction = intent.getAction();
            if (intent.hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) &&
                    intentAction != null && intentAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)) {
                finish();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Services get killed based on the resource situation. If the installer is still running, it has of course a high priority because it is visible to the user. Have you checked the memory consumption while you start your service with *open* from the installer?

Comment: But my service is foreground service then why os kill it instantly.

Comment: @AnkitHTech True. But only as long as there is any memory left, no? ;)

Comment: @AnkitHTech Of course, I meant _any memory left_ while the installer is also running. That's why I asked whether you were analyzing the memory situation.

Comment: memory seems to be fine but still the same result